# How do I create a program that details files and their sub directories?

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

There is a program that I am working on and Im absolutly lost even at how to begin this. I am using Visual Studio C# Windows App Form.

What I need to do is allow the user to enter any path location they want and the program will return the Name of the file/folder; Path; date and size, and this will also be done for sub directories.

I found some code in the MSDN site and I am trying to use it and modify it for the first part of this project, but keep receiving error messages. Some of the messages indicate that there is more than one entry ie (static void Main() and using namespace Detailed).

This is what I have so far, a form with rich text box and the FolderBrowserDialog and it seems as I can't get beyond this point without so many errors.

This is under Form1.Designer.cs:

```
<i>namespace Detailed
```

{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.folderBrowserDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.openFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // folderBrowserDialog1
        // 
        this.folderBrowserDialog1.HelpRequest += new System.EventHandler(this.folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest);
        // 
        // richTextBox1
        // 
        this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 32);
        this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
        this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(167, 23);
        this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
        // 
        // openFileDialog1
        // 
        this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "openFileDialog1";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1;
}
```

}

For the For1.cs this is what I have so far:

*using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;*

public class FolderBrowserDialogExampleForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1;
    private OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1;

```
private RichTextBox richTextBox1;

private MainMenu mainMenu1;
private MenuItem fileMenuItem, openMenuItem;
private MenuItem folderMenuItem, closeMenuItem;

private string openFileName, folderName;

private bool fileOpened = false;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // FolderBrowserDialogExampleForm
    // 
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.Name = "FolderBrowserDialogExampleForm";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

}

I'm still new to programing and hope I can get this figured out asap as I was requested to have this no later than Thursday morning est. I had the Rich TextBox in the Form, but removed it because of too many errors.

This is the code I found. I know this is just part of what I need to do, but when reading through the code I noticed that maybe I can apply what is needed to the form and then break up the code and put the pieces of code where I need them.  [This is the code I am following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)

Here is an error message I am receiving with Form1.Designer.cs - there are 14 of these same errors: 
‘Detailed.form1’ does not contain a definition for ‘Form1_Load’ and no extension method ‘Form1_Load’ accepting a first argument of type ‘Detailed.Form1’ could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you spend all Wednesday going through C# Windows Forms programming tutorials, then you'll have this cooked up on Thursday morning easy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want is a dialog prompting the user for a directory.
So get rid of all that code, start a new project win form and place a textbox in your form and a button in your form.

Simple enough one text box and one button.  Now in the click event of your button "Browse", have you, you write code to open an instance of the `FolderBrowserDialog` class and you `.ShowDialog()`.
To get this path:

Here is a sample screen output:

[image]

The code is fairly straightforward, look at my picture and how much code i have to do this.

Comment: Ok, I did what you had said, but the code I found was "            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new
FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();" The only issue with this is the textbox. and f. (except for these two it does open the browser and allow the user to select where they want to go).